# problem running script on receiving emai

Tags: linux, postfix

I would like to run a script when an email is received. I added this line to /etc/aliases

myuser: "|/home/myuser/mailer.rb"

When I send an email to myuser@domain, I see permission denied error in the maillog.

Aug 12 14:17:59 stag postfix/local[29300]: E5B8F67024F: to=, relay=local, delay=1596, delays=1596/0.01/0/0.02, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (temporary failure. Command output: local: fatal: execvp /home/myuser/mailer.rb: Permission denied )

The permission on mailer.rb is 755. Why would I get a permission denied error?

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you get as far as the script with that user? I'm guessing it can't open the user's home directory. Try
`sudo -u postfix /home/myuser/mailer.rb` to confirm this. To fix it, which distro are you running?

Comment: When I try running as postfix, I get the error "Sorry, user myuser is not allowed to execute "/home/myuser/mailer.rb" as postfix.

I am running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)

Comment: Are you sure it's not "sorry user postfix is not allowed to execute"? Try doing  
`sudo -u postfix ls -la /home/myuser/mailer.rb` to see if it can even find it. If not:  
`setfacl -m user:postfix:r-x /home/myuser`  
If it can, but just can't execute it, try:  
`setfacl -m user:postfix:r-x /home/myuser/mailer.rb`

Comment: Yeah, even I noticed that error message and am confused. It is "myuser not allowed to execute as postfix". I can't do anything as sudo -u postfix. It asks for password and when I enter the myuser password, it gives me the same not allowed to execute message.

Comment: Sorry this is my oversight, the sudo command I gave you needs to be run as root.

Comment: So, I found out that it was running as user "nobody". So, I executed setfacl on user "nobody" and it works now! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Is SELinux enabled? You can check that with `getenforce`. If it returns **enforcing**, then SELinux is on and can cause that kind of problems. If you don't need SELinux, you may temporarily disable it with `setenforce 0` and see if it cures the problem.

If it does, you may permanently disable SELinux by modifying file **/etc/selinux/config**.

Comment: Looks like it is disabled

$ /usr/sbin/getenforce 
Disabled